# Adding image in a text field in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, dart

I want to add images in a text field/text form field in flutter. Whenever the user clicks the first button in the bottom navigation bar, the app will ask to pick an image and the image will display in the text field.
**Like this**:-
[image]

How Can I add one? (I am not talking about emoji)
ANY HELP OR IDEA WOULD BE APPRECIATED.

Comment: you should use `RichTextEditor` https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android

Comment: @Priyankagb Thanks so much for the GitHub link. I will surely look for that.

Comment: @Priyankagb Can you please tell me how can I use this for my flutter app?

Comment: here it is https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr/versions/1.0.0-dev.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RichTextEditor` using [rich_text_view](https://pub.dev/packages/rich_text_view/) plugin to support stylized text. Another option here is by using [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown) to render images from Markdown.